# Grouping strings with same composition

Tags: arrays, go, anagram

I want to grouping strings with the same composition using Go.

Let's say I have array of string like this:

```
['kita', 'atik', 'tika', 'aku', 'kia', 'makan', 'kua']
```

and the expected output is like this

```
[
 ["kita", "atik", "tika"],
 ["aku", "kua"],
 ["makan"],
 ["kia"]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable using maps:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    words := []string{"kita", "atik", "tika", "aku", "kia", "makan", "kua"}
    refs := map[string][]string{}

    for _, word := range words {
        // normalizing word
        r := []rune(word)
        sort.Slice(r, func(i, j int) bool { return r[i] < r[j] })
        sortedWord := string(r)

        // appending in the normalized word map
        refs[sortedWord] = append(refs[sortedWord], word)
    }

    // transforming into a slice of slices
    result := [][]string{}
    for _, item := range refs {
        result = append(result, item)
    }

    log.Println(result)
}
```